# Program that reads other .py

Tags: python

I am coding a Python program to be able to read another .py file and make a report of its content.
The data that I need is related to the libraries, functions and variables used in that .py. 
I tried to use inspect library but this requires to import that .py and I can't see all its globals.

Is there a library to perform in a better way this task?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to treat this .py file as a simple text file and open it with Python's [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) built-in function?

Then use the [regular expression module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to search patterns in the string inside the .py file?

Answer (score 0):

Considering @gillu13's reply, you could also use the open() function and then the built-in compile() function to retrieve a code object, on which you could base your report:

```
code_obj = compile(file_contents, "somefilename", "eval")
```